# Testing MySQL 32-bit ODBC connection via CMD

Tags: windows, mysql, batch, odbc

I'm going to make a batch script to do some basic troubleshooting.
Among other things, I want to test 32-bit MySQL ODBC's for connectivity. This script will run locally on each workstation. There doesnt appear to be any option in odbcconf.exe for this.

Comment: Maybe see http://serverfault.com/questions/450557/migrating-odbc-information-through-a-batch-file/451009#451009

Comment: Not quite what i'm looking for. I simply want to test the connection, not create a new odbc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
sqlcmd.exe -U MyLogin -P MyPassword -S ComputerName\InstanceName | find "connected"
```

If the connection succeeds, then you know your ODBC connection is good.

Also, check out this big article on scripting with sqlcmd:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx